# Apple отклоняет приложение для AppleWatch

Tags: swift, xcode

У меня произошла такая проблема : я написал приложение для Apple watch в среде Xcode и отправил в app store. Заранее скажу, приложение не предназначается для загрузки на iPhone или iPad, как и многие приложение для часов оно только должно загрузиться из app store на часы никуда более! Это и стало причиной отклонение Apple комиссией. Вот что они сказали:

> Guideline 2.3 - Performance - Accurate Metadata.
>   We were unable to install the app on actual iPhone & iPad. The UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key in the Info.plist is set in such a way that the app will not install on an actual iPhone & iPad.
>   Next Steps:
>   To resolve this issue, please check the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key to verify that it contains only the attributes required for your app features or the attributes that must not be present on the device. Attributes specified by a dictionary should be set to true if they are required and false if they must not be present on the device.

вот, но я не понимаю как мне сделать так чтобы приложение шло как бы только на AppleWatch, я не понимаю как мне и где это сделать(в xcode или где?) чтобы приложение не предполагалось для айпада и телефона, чтобы они вообще не пытались его туда скачать что бы понимали что это только на AppleWatch. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/creating_independent_watchos_apps

Comment: @schmidt9 на сайте указана походу устаревшая информация, у меня нет такой галочки где можно пометить что "Supports Running Without iOS App Installation”

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57239860/3004003

Comment: @schmidt9 я же говорю у меня нету в Xcode данной штуки что бы поставить галочку в том месте у меня там просто выбор версии а галочки никакой нет. пост который ты скинул был выложен 6 месяцев назад возможно в Xcode изменили данную функцию..

Comment: Если вы ещё не решили данную проблему, то предлагаю вам спросить в конфе посвящённой разработке под эппл. Там наверняка вам помогут: https://t.me/swiftbook_chat

Answer (score 0):

В XCode 11.2 для отвязки приложения для WatchOS галка ставится здесь

**Дополнение**

Проверьте содержимое ключа `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` в `Info.plist` ваших таргетов, возможно там есть ненужные значения, как указано например [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39676589/watch-os3-uirequireddevicecapabilities-issue-during-itc-review)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня приложение чисто для Apple Watch а не смешанное телефонное и apple watch, у меня такой галки вообще нет, она появляется только если я создаю проект Phone&AppleWatch